# How to validate if entered time is greater than previously entered datepicker controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetime, infragistics

Here I am using windows forms application with VB.NET. I am creating a simple basic form which helps to dynamically create some datetimepicker infragistics controls dynamically inside infragistics panel.

Below is the screenshot of the form

[image]

Now on Save button click I am looping through each datepicker and saving its value with id in datatabase.

Now i want to have validate alert message, like if the user tries to enter date less than previously entered date pickers. then it should validate something like date you have entered is less than previously datetime values.

Here's my save button click code

```
Private Sub UltraButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UltraButtonSave.Click
    If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")) AndAlso Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")) Then
        ScreenProperty.ARG_ConveyanceID = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")
        ScreenProperty.ARG_TripID = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")
        For Each o As Object In UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls
            If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
                Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o
                ScreenProperty.ARG_CheckPointTimeID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(0))
                ScreenProperty.ARG_TerminalCheckPointID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(1))
                ScreenProperty.ARG_CheckPointTimeValue = datePicker.Value
                Helper.InsertCheckPointTimesScreen(CType(ScreenProperty, KMCommonUITemplates.CUTScreenProperty), Me)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Order does not have Trip/Conveyance created.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dont assume the users are going to make selections in the order you want them to ("previously entered").  They wont always do that.  Validate the selections when they try to save

Answer (score 0):

Just create 3 variables namely:

```
OriginalScheduled
Original1stLine
Originaldock
```

Populate these variables upon getting data from the database (opening the form). Then when dates are changed, compare it to the original values that you have.